# Differences between re.match, re.search, re.fullmatch

Tags: python, regex

From the [regex docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) it says that:

**Pattern.match(...)**

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match this regular expression

**Pattern.fullmatch(...)**

> If the whole string matches this regular expression

**Pattern.search(...)**

> Scan through string looking for the first location where this regular expression produces a match

Given the above, why couldn't someone just always use `search` to do everything? For example:

```
re.search(r'...'   # search
re.search(r'^...'  or re.search(r'\A...'   # match
re.search(r'^...$' or re.search(r'\A...\Z' # fullmatch
```

Are `match` and `fullmatch` just shortcuts (if they could be called that) for the `search` method? Or do they have other uses that I'm overlooking?

Comment: First difference: `re.matchall` doesn't exist.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it was a mistype. they meant `fullmatch`

Comment: Yes, they're just shortcuts.

Comment: The most important is that the different method names make sense and inform about your intension.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'd vote to reopen the question, I think it's a bit different than the answers in that link

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I disagree. The question here is the exact same as the one there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's not the exact same, no answer there even mentions `fullmatch` (although it does make an appearance in the comments)

Comment: @Ruzihm The details are easily extrapolated.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice While similar, the questions are different. I found this post while searching the difference between `match` and `fullmatch`. The linked "duplicate" does not answer that question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Giving credit for [@Ruzihm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774091/3600709) since parts of my answer derive from his.

---

#### Quick overview

A quick rundown of the differences:

- `re.match` is anchored at the start `^pattern`

  - Ensures the string begins with the pattern
- `re.fullmatch` is anchored at the start and end of the pattern `^pattern$`

  - Ensures the full string matches the pattern (can be especially useful with alternations as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899892/can-re-fullmatch-eliminate-the-need-for-string-anchors-in-regex))
- `re.search` is not anchored `pattern`

  - Ensures the string contains the pattern

A more in-depth comparison of `re.match` vs `re.search` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

---

With examples:

```
aa            # string
a|aa          # regex

re.match:     a
re.search:    a
re.fullmatch: aa
```

```
ab            # string
^a            # regex

re.match:     a
re.search:    a
re.fullmatch: # None (no match)
```

---

#### So what about `\A` and `\Z` anchors?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) states the following:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

And in the `Pattern.fullmatch` section it says:

> If the whole string matches this regular expression, return a corresponding match object.

And, as initially found and quoted by Ruzihm in his answer:

> Note however that in MULTILINE mode match() only matches at the
>   beginning of the string, whereas using search() with a regular
>   expression beginning with `^` will match at the beginning of each
>   line.
>
> ```
> >>> re.match('X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # No match
> >>> re.search('^X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # Match
> <re.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='X'>
> ```

```
\A^A
B
X$\Z

# re.match('X', s)                  no match
# re.search('^X', s)                no match

# ------------------------------------------
# and the string above when re.MULTILINE is enabled effectively becomes

\A^A$
^B$
^C$\Z

# re.match('X', s, re.MULTILINE)    no match
# re.search('^X', s, re.MULTILINE)  match X
```

With regards to `\A` and `\Z`, neither performs differently for `re.MULTILINE` since `\A` and `\Z` are effectively the only `^` and `$` in the whole string.

So using `\A` and `\Z` with any of the three methods yields the same results.

---

#### Answer (line anchors vs string anchors)

What this tells me is that `re.match` and `re.fullmatch` don't match *line anchors* `^` and `$` respectively, but that they instead match *string anchors* `\A` and `\Z` respectively.

Comment: thanks (again) for the detailed answer. What about using \A and \Z though, does that render them the same?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, they can be seen as shortcuts of `re.search` calls that start with `\A` or start with `\A` and end with `\Z`.

Because `\A` always specifies the beginning of the string, using `re.search` and prepending `\A` seems to equate `re.match`, even under MULTILINE mode. Some examples:

```
import re
haystack = "A\nB\nZ"

matchstring = 'A'
x=re.match(matchstring, haystack) # Match
y=re.search('\A' + matchstring, haystack) # Match

matchstring = 'A$\nB'
x=re.match(matchstring, haystack, re.MULTILINE) # Match
y=re.search('\A' + matchstring, haystack, re.MULTILINE) # Match

matchstring = 'A\n$B'
x=re.match(matchstring, haystack, re.MULTILINE) # No match
y=re.search('\A' + matchstring, haystack, re.MULTILINE) # No match
```

The same is true for putting the search string between `\A` and `\Z` to equate `fullmatch`.

---

#### Not including `\A` / `\Z`:

No, they treat MULTILINE differently. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Note however that in MULTILINE mode `match()` only matches at the
>   beginning of the string, whereas using `search()` with a regular
>   expression beginning with `'^'` will match at the beginning of each
>   line.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> >>> re.match('X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # No match
> >>> re.search('^X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # Match
> <re.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='X'>
> ```

Likewise, in MULTILINE mode, `fullmatch()` matches at the beginning and end of the string, and `search()` with `'^...$'` matches at the beginning and end of each line.

---

Comment: @Ruzihm, what about using \A and \Z then instead of ^ and $? Would that make them always-equivalent?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 excellent point. I edited my answer to address that. I couldn't find a difference, even when profiling their runtime (not shown in answer)